# Generate combinations from list within column

Tags: pandas

We have a DataFrame with 2 columns as follows:

```
|Type   |list_dates  |  
|:----:|:-----------:|  
|1    |['a','b','c']|  
|2    |['d','e','f','g']|
```

We need to generate a combination of all list elements while duplicating the Type, as follows:

```
|Type   |list_dates  |  
|:----:|:-----------:|  
|1    |['a','b']|  
|1    |['a','c']|  
|1    |['b','c']|  
|2    |['d','e']|  
|2    |['e','f']|  
.....
```

In order to generate the combinations we are using the following code:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(df.list_dates,2) )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pure python solution working best.
So first create tuples by `dict` and then create `list of tuples` by combinations. Last create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
import itertools

L = []
for x, y in zip(df['Type'], df['list_dates']):
    a = list(itertools.combinations(y,2))
    for i in a:
        L.append((x, list(i)))
```

Or nested `list comprehension` solution:

```
L = [(x, list(i)) for x, y in zip(df['Type'], df['list_dates']) 
                  for i in list(itertools.combinations(y,2))]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Type','list_dates'])
print (df)

   Type list_dates
0     1     [a, b]
1     1     [a, c]
2     1     [b, c]
3     2     [d, e]
4     2     [d, f]
5     2     [d, g]
6     2     [e, f]
7     2     [e, g]
8     2     [f, g]
```

Thanks, [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389117/generate-combinations-from-list-within-column/47389464?noredirect=1#comment81732516_47389464) for nice suggestion - if `DataFrame` have only `2 columns`:

```
import itertools

L = []
for x, y in df.values:
    a = list(itertools.combinations(y,2))
    for i in a:
        L.append((x, list(i)))

L = [(x, list(i)) for x, y in df.values for i in list(itertools.combinations(y,2))]
```

If more columns first filter:

```
L = [(x, list(i)) for x, y in df[['Type','list_dates']].values 
                  for i in list(itertools.combinations(y,2))]
```

Comment: You don't need the `zip` `pd.DataFrame([[x, list(y)] for x, z in df.values for y in itertools.combinations(z, 2)], columns=['Type','list_dates'])`

Comment: Great! Thank you